# What are the options for shipping luggage to the US from Vietnam?

Tags: usa, luggage, vietnam, shipping

I'm going to be traveling in Vietnam and would like to bring along expensive and heavy camera equipment, but afterwards have the freedom to go backpacking elsewhere in SE Asia without the extra weight.

What are my options for this type of thing? The equipment will be around 25lbs and $5000 in value. I'd like the shipping to be the most reliable possible with insurance. The transit time will not be an issue because I'll be traveling.

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  Is this time or cost critical?

Comment: Options? there's going to be literally dozens of carriers.  Do you just want the cheapest, or most reliable, or fastest courier out there?
Have you tried a google search or found anything so far, or was this your first stop?

Comment: Voted to close.  Because there are many options and companies that can do this that are present on the web, and probably a few more that aren't we need limiting conditions.  As it stands you can try the usual suspects like Postal Service, Fedex, DHL as your package is not that heavy.

Comment: @user1009762 It is appropriate if you can limit the criteria if all you need to do a search of who can ship from Vietnam to USA, which yielded about a dozen possible solutions just on a first page of results from Google.  If you have criteria more specific then insured 25lb package please edit the question and vote to reopen.

Comment: @user1009762 great, and I still think it could be a valid question, you just need to be more specific.  (See my questions above). If you edit  your question to include those details, and flag it to be reopened, I think we could get it answered.

Comment: Anyone able to answer this?